# Redirect network logs from syslog to another file

Tags: 12.04, networking, log

I keep logging way to much info (not needed, for now) in my `syslog`, and not daily or hourly... but instant. If I want to watch for something in my `syslog` I just can't because the network log keeps interfering.

So, how can I redirect network logs to another file and/or stop logging it?

```
Dec 10 17:01:33 user kernel: [ 8716.000587] MediaState is connected
Dec 10 17:01:33 user kernel: [ 8716.000599] ==>rt_ioctl_giwmode(mode=2)
Dec 10 17:01:33 user kernel: [ 8716.000601] ==>rt_ioctl_giwfreq  11
Dec 10 17:01:33 user kernel: [ 8716.000612] rt28xx_get_wireless_stats --->
Dec 10 17:01:33 user kernel: [ 8716.000615] <--- rt28xx_get_wireless_stats
Dec 10 17:01:39 user kernel: [ 8722.000714] MediaState is connected
Dec 10 17:01:39 user kernel: [ 8722.000729] ==>rt_ioctl_giwmode(mode=2)
Dec 10 17:01:39 user kernel: [ 8722.000732] ==>rt_ioctl_giwfreq  11
Dec 10 17:01:39 user kernel: [ 8722.000747] rt28xx_get_wireless_stats --->
Dec 10 17:01:39 user kernel: [ 8722.000751] <--- rt28xx_get_wireless_stats
Dec 10 17:01:44 user kernel: [ 8726.904025] QuickDRS: TxTotalCnt <= 15, train back to original rate 
Dec 10 17:01:45 user kernel: [ 8728.003138] MediaState is connected
Dec 10 17:01:45 user kernel: [ 8728.003153] ==>rt_ioctl_giwmode(mode=2)
Dec 10 17:01:45 user kernel: [ 8728.003157] ==>rt_ioctl_giwfreq  11
Dec 10 17:01:45 user kernel: [ 8728.003171] rt28xx_get_wireless_stats --->
Dec 10 17:01:45 user kernel: [ 8728.003175] <--- rt28xx_get_wireless_stats
Dec 10 17:01:51 user kernel: [ 8734.004066] MediaState is connected
Dec 10 17:01:51 user kernel: [ 8734.004079] ==>rt_ioctl_giwmode(mode=2)
Dec 10 17:01:51 user kernel: [ 8734.004082] ==>rt_ioctl_giwfreq  11
Dec 10 17:01:51 user kernel: [ 8734.004096] rt28xx_get_wireless_stats --->
Dec 10 17:01:51 user kernel: [ 8734.004099] <--- rt28xx_get_wireless_stats
Dec 10 17:01:57 user kernel: [ 8740.004108] MediaState is connected
Dec 10 17:01:57 user kernel: [ 8740.004119] ==>rt_ioctl_giwmode(mode=2)
Dec 10 17:01:57 user kernel: [ 8740.004121] ==>rt_ioctl_giwfreq  11
Dec 10 17:01:57 user kernel: [ 8740.004132] rt28xx_get_wireless_stats --->
Dec 10 17:01:57 user kernel: [ 8740.004135] <--- rt28xx_get_wireless_stats
Dec 10 17:01:57 user kernel: [ 8740.436021] QuickDRS: TxTotalCnt <= 15, train back to original rate 
Dec 10 17:02:03 user kernel: [ 8746.005280] MediaState is connected
Dec 10 17:02:03 user kernel: [ 8746.005294] ==>rt_ioctl_giwmode(mode=2)
Dec 10 17:02:03 user kernel: [ 8746.005298] ==>rt_ioctl_giwfreq  11
Dec 10 17:02:03 user kernel: [ 8746.005312] rt28xx_get_wireless_stats --->
Dec 10 17:02:03 user kernel: [ 8746.005315] <--- rt28xx_get_wireless_stats
Dec 10 17:02:09 user kernel: [ 8752.004790] MediaState is connected
Dec 10 17:02:09 user kernel: [ 8752.004804] ==>rt_ioctl_giwmode(mode=2)
Dec 10 17:02:09 user kernel: [ 8752.004808] ==>rt_ioctl_giwfreq  11
Dec 10 17:02:09 user kernel: [ 8752.004821] rt28xx_get_wireless_stats --->
Dec 10 17:02:09 user kernel: [ 8752.004825] <--- rt28xx_get_wireless_stats
Dec 10 17:02:15 user kernel: [ 8757.984031] QuickDRS: TxTotalCnt <= 15, train back to original rate 
Dec 10 17:02:15 user kernel: [ 8758.004078] MediaState is connected
Dec 10 17:02:15 user kernel: [ 8758.004094] ==>rt_ioctl_giwmode(mode=2)
Dec 10 17:02:15 user kernel: [ 8758.004097] ==>rt_ioctl_giwfreq  11
Dec 10 17:02:15 user kernel: [ 8758.004112] rt28xx_get_wireless_stats --->
Dec 10 17:02:15 user kernel: [ 8758.004116] <--- rt28xx_get_wireless_stats
Dec 10 17:02:16 user kernel: [ 8759.492017] QuickDRS: TxTotalCnt <= 15, train back to original rate 
Dec 10 17:02:19 user kernel: [ 8762.002179] SCANNING, suspend MSDU transmission ...
Dec 10 17:02:19 user kernel: [ 8762.004291] MlmeScanReqAction -- Send PSM Data frame for off channel RM, SCAN_IN_PROGRESS=1!
Dec 10 17:02:19 user kernel: [ 8762.025055] SYNC - BBP R4 to 20MHz.l
Dec 10 17:02:19 user kernel: [ 8762.027249] RT35xx: SwitchChannel#1(RF=8, Pwr0=30, Pwr1=25, 2T), N=0xF1, K=0x02, R=0x02
Dec 10 17:02:19 user kernel: [ 8762.170206] RT35xx: SwitchChannel#2(RF=8, Pwr0=30, Pwr1=25, 2T), N=0xF1, K=0x07, R=0x02
Dec 10 17:02:19 user kernel: [ 8762.318211] RT35xx: SwitchChannel#3(RF=8, Pwr0=30, Pwr1=25, 2T), N=0xF2, K=0x02, R=0x02
Dec 10 17:02:19 user kernel: [ 8762.462269] RT35xx: SwitchChannel#4(RF=8, Pwr0=30, Pwr1=25, 2T), N=0xF2, K=0x07, R=0x02
Dec 10 17:02:19 user kernel: [ 8762.606229] RT35xx: SwitchChannel#5(RF=8, Pwr0=30, Pwr1=25, 2T), N=0xF3, K=0x02, R=0x02
Dec 10 17:02:19 user kernel: [ 8762.750202] RT35xx: SwitchChannel#6(RF=8, Pwr0=30, Pwr1=25, 2T), N=0xF3, K=0x07, R=0x02
Dec 10 17:02:20 user kernel: [ 8762.894217] RT35xx: SwitchChannel#7(RF=8, Pwr0=29, Pwr1=26, 2T), N=0xF4, K=0x02, R=0x02
Dec 10 17:02:20 user kernel: [ 8763.038202] RT35xx: SwitchChannel#11(RF=8, Pwr0=29, Pwr1=26, 2T), N=0xF6, K=0x02, R=0x02
Dec 10 17:02:20 user kernel: [ 8763.040194] CntlEnqueueForRecv(): BAR-Wcid(1), Tid (0)
Dec 10 17:02:20 user kernel: [ 8763.040199] BAR(1) : Tid (0) - 03a3:037e
Dec 10 17:02:20 user kernel: [ 8763.040387] SYNC - End of SCAN, restore to channel 11, Total BSS[03]
Dec 10 17:02:20 user kernel: [ 8763.040400] ScanNextChannel -- Send PSM Data frame
Dec 10 17:02:20 user kernel: [ 8763.040402] bFastRoamingScan ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Get back to send data ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Dec 10 17:02:20 user kernel: [ 8763.040405] SCAN done, resume MSDU transmission ...
Dec 10 17:02:20 user kernel: [ 8763.047022] CntlEnqueueForRecv(): BAR-Wcid(1), Tid (0)
Dec 10 17:02:20 user kernel: [ 8763.047026] BAR(1) : Tid (0) - 03a3:03a5
Dec 10 17:02:21 user kernel: [ 8763.898130] bImprovedScan ............. Resume for bImprovedScan, SCAN_PENDING .............. 
Dec 10 17:02:21 user kernel: [ 8763.898143] SCANNING, suspend MSDU transmission ...
Dec 10 17:02:21 user kernel: [ 8763.900245] MlmeScanReqAction -- Send PSM Data frame for off channel RM, SCAN_IN_PROGRESS=1!
Dec 10 17:02:21 user kernel: [ 8763.921144] SYNC - BBP R4 to 20MHz.l
Dec 10 17:02:21 user kernel: [ 8763.923339] RT35xx: SwitchChannel#8(RF=8, Pwr0=29, Pwr1=26, 2T), N=0xF4, K=0x07, R=0x02
Dec 10 17:02:21 user kernel: [ 8763.996019] QuickDRS: TxTotalCnt <= 15, train back to original rate 
Dec 10 17:02:21 user kernel: [ 8764.066221] RT35xx: SwitchChannel#9(RF=8, Pwr0=29, Pwr1=26, 2T), N=0xF5, K=0x02, R=0x02
Dec 10 17:02:21 user kernel: [ 8764.210212] RT35xx: SwitchChannel#10(RF=8, Pwr0=29, Pwr1=26, 2T), N=0xF5, K=0x07, R=0x02
Dec 10 17:02:21 user kernel: [ 8764.215536] CntlEnqueueForRecv(): BAR-Wcid(1), Tid (0)
Dec 10 17:02:21 user kernel: [ 8764.215542] BAR(1) : Tid (0) - 0457:0452
Dec 10 17:02:21 user kernel: [ 8764.244000] CntlEnqueueForRecv(): BAR-Wcid(1), Tid (0)
Dec 10 17:02:21 user kernel: [ 8764.244004] BAR(1) : Tid (0) - 0459:0456
Dec 10 17:02:21 user kernel: [ 8764.253019] CntlEnqueueForRecv(): BAR-Wcid(1), Tid (0)
Dec 10 17:02:21 user kernel: [ 8764.253023] BAR(1) : Tid (0) - 045c:0458
Dec 10 17:02:21 user kernel: [ 8764.256677] CntlEnqueueForRecv(): BAR-Wcid(1), Tid (0)
Dec 10 17:02:21 user kernel: [ 8764.256681] BAR(1) : Tid (0) - 045c:045b
Dec 10 17:02:21 user kernel: [ 8764.259785] CntlEnqueueForRecv(): BAR-Wcid(1), Tid (0)
Dec 10 17:02:21 user kernel: [ 8764.259788] BAR(1) : Tid (0) - 045d:045b
Dec 10 17:02:21 user kernel: [ 8764.280467] CntlEnqueueForRecv(): BAR-Wcid(1), Tid (0)
Dec 10 17:02:21 user kernel: [ 8764.280471] BAR(1) : Tid (0) - 045f:045c
Dec 10 17:02:21 user kernel: [ 8764.282189] CntlEnqueueForRecv(): BAR-Wcid(1), Tid (0)
Dec 10 17:02:21 user kernel: [ 8764.282192] BAR(1) : Tid (0) - 045f:045e
Dec 10 17:02:21 user kernel: [ 8764.354204] RT35xx: SwitchChannel#11(RF=8, Pwr0=29, Pwr1=26, 2T), N=0xF6, K=0x02, R=0x02
Dec 10 17:02:21 user kernel: [ 8764.356408] ScanNextChannel():Send PWA NullData frame to notify the associated AP!
Dec 10 17:02:21 user kernel: [ 8764.498202] RT35xx: SwitchChannel#12(RF=8, Pwr0=29, Pwr1=26, 2T), N=0xF6, K=0x07, R=0x02
Dec 10 17:02:21 user kernel: [ 8764.642210] RT35xx: SwitchChannel#13(RF=8, Pwr0=30, Pwr1=28, 2T), N=0xF7, K=0x02, R=0x02
Dec 10 17:02:22 user kernel: [ 8764.790229] RT35xx: SwitchChannel#14(RF=8, Pwr0=30, Pwr1=28, 2T), N=0xF8, K=0x04, R=0x02
Dec 10 17:02:22 user kernel: [ 8764.934238] RT35xx: SwitchChannel#11(RF=8, Pwr0=29, Pwr1=26, 2T), N=0xF6, K=0x02, R=0x02
Dec 10 17:02:22 user kernel: [ 8764.935243] CntlEnqueueForRecv(): BAR-Wcid(1), Tid (0)
Dec 10 17:02:22 user kernel: [ 8764.935249] BAR(1) : Tid (0) - 048e:0485
Dec 10 17:02:22 user kernel: [ 8764.936423] SYNC - End of SCAN, restore to channel 11, Total BSS[05]
Dec 10 17:02:22 user kernel: [ 8764.936436] ScanNextChannel -- Send PSM Data frame
Dec 10 17:02:22 user kernel: [ 8764.936440] SCAN done, resume MSDU transmission ...
Dec 10 17:02:22 user kernel: [ 8764.940529] RT35xx: SwitchChannel#11(RF=8, Pwr0=29, Pwr1=26, 2T), N=0xF6, K=0x02, R=0x02
Dec 10 17:02:22 user kernel: [ 8764.942178] CntlEnqueueForRecv(): BAR-Wcid(1), Tid (0)
Dec 10 17:02:22 user kernel: [ 8764.942182] BAR(1) : Tid (0) - 0493:048e
Dec 10 17:02:22 user kernel: [ 8764.942715] CNTL - All roaming failed, restore to channel 11, Total BSS[05]
Dec 10 17:02:22 user kernel: [ 8764.948016] MMCHK - No BEACON. restore R66 to the low bound(56) 
Dec 10 17:02:22 user kernel: [ 8764.948307] ===>rt_ioctl_giwscan. 5(5) BSS returned, data->length = 1111
Dec 10 17:02:23 user kernel: [ 8766.048073] QuickDRS: TxTotalCnt <= 15, train back to original rate 
Dec 10 17:02:23 user kernel: [ 8766.552034] QuickDRS: TxTotalCnt <= 15, train back to original rate 
Dec 10 17:02:27 user kernel: [ 8770.001180] MediaState is connected
Dec 10 17:02:27 user kernel: [ 8770.001197] ==>rt_ioctl_giwmode(mode=2)
Dec 10 17:02:27 user kernel: [ 8770.001201] ==>rt_ioctl_giwfreq  11
Dec 10 17:02:27 user kernel: [ 8770.001219] rt28xx_get_wireless_stats --->
Dec 10 17:02:27 user kernel: [ 8770.001223] <--- rt28xx_get_wireless_stats
Dec 10 17:02:28 user kernel: [ 8771.564020] QuickDRS: TxTotalCnt <= 15, train back to original rate 
Dec 10 17:02:29 user kernel: [ 8772.064031] QuickDRS: TxTotalCnt <= 15, train back to original rate
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of what your calling a network log? There are several things that could generate network entries.

Comment: @coteyr I've updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your output that looks like debug logs from the network chip is just way to noisy. unfortunately, unless that module has some options (a quick look on Google shows the only options to be at compile time), I don't think your going to be able to do what you want.

Check `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` and check the first for lines for something like  `*.*;auth,authpriv.none`

change it to
`*.err;auth,authpriv.none`

There will be a file path on the end of the line. However this will quite all logging down. Something that you may not want to do.

You could instead, when you need to read that file do a

`tail /var/log/syslog -n 1000 | grep -v "RT35xx|rt28xx`

using -v will show only lines not matching and the argument is regex so you could get more complicated. However it looks as if that driver is just evil and the developers need a whomping for making it too verbose.

So, to recap:

First try turning down the verbosity of the driver. That would be your best option.
Next create some kind of grep statement that will filter out the lines you don't want.
Finally, if nothing else works, or you don't care, turn down logging.

If you deiced to turn down logging note that you can be more selective and jsut turn down kernel logging. However I don't really recommend it.

Comment: On Ubuntu, the default `rsyslog` logging rules are in `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`, while `/etc/rsyslog.conf` contains the default configuration for `rsyslog`.

Comment: updated to reflect location and current defaults.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu forum (https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1708767) suggests next command for disabling such noisy output from the wireless driver:

```
iwpriv ra0 set Debug=0
```